# Which foods or drinks reduce headache?

Tags: food, drinks, paint

Which type of food or drinks reduce headache quickly?

Comment: Are we talking migraine level, a slight headache, or somewhere in between?

Comment: And the kind of headache or especially cause can make a huge difference.

Comment: Kindly explain your question. What type of headache you have? Is it generated from stress or any other kind of headache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To cure a headache you need to know the cause- or test options based on a suspected cause.

Tiredness => sleep.

- If you can't sleep get antioxidant and electrolyte rich stuff.
- avoid coffee. Drink/eat real fruits and veggie based stuff and gatorade helps.

Dehydration=> need water. Just any pure liquids. Avoid Coffee because that will only make you more dehydrated.

Hungry => eat food and rest a bit.

Answer (score 4):

To mention the medicine:

- Paracetamol, obviously.
- Ibuprofene, which works even better for me, but should be taken during some meal.

Now to answer your question:

- **Infusions** work very well for me. Just to name a few: tea, rooibos, chamomile, tilia, verbena…

The only downside is that it's indeed diuretic. Drinking an infusion even several hours before going to bed is a big no-no for me. I prefer a small headache over having to get up multiple times before even falling asleep.

Also, sometimes I'm just not in the mood to drink an infusion :)

But the above solutions are only symptomatic. You may want to consider long-term solutions, actually fixing the causes:

Physically:

- You may be dehydrated to some level. Get the habit to drink more water during the day. Dehydration can be checked in blood tests, think about taking the opportunity of a future exam to ask to add a check for this.
- Fresh air is a big plus. The most you can, avoid breathing tobacco, pollution, chemicals…
- Wrongly eating (excess of sugar, etc.) causes headache. Improve this, if applicable.

Mentally:

- Try to determine if events trigger the headache. In my case, these are: annoying and recurrent noises, angsting thoughts… Solve these root causes the most you can.
- If there are situations where you feel good, headache-less, such as being in some places or doing some things, increase the duration of these situations. This increased "recovery time" will mechanically bring a better and more durable recover.

Comment: peppermint is meant to be good to relieve headaches, so a peppermint tea could work for some people.

Answer (score 1):

I suffer from migraines and headaches in general. In my answer I am going to assume you are talking about a headache and not a migraine (the latter being so complex you could write a book full of advice).

What to drink really depends on why you have a headache. I usually drink water, but it doesn't really help too much to be honest - the cause of my headaches are not dehydration. Water can really help with a headache caused by a hangover.

Another common cause of a headache is caffeine withdrawal. This is commonly known as the "weekend headache" because you are getting up later and drinking less caffeine. In these cases you could drink a cup of coffee or tea - and in fact many headache tablets actually contain caffeine. For these reasons I have a strict routine of drinking black tea (one in the morning and one in the afternoon) which I adhere to every day of the week. If I can't find a tea or coffee I will drink a soda/cold drink with caffeine in it (e.g. Coke) but I will always follow with a meal to avoid a sugar rush and subsequent sugar crash headache.

If your headaches are accompanied by stress in your body (e.g. a sore neck) then you can try a warm compress and a/or massage. You can try take a magnesium tablet too.

If your headaches are caused by sinus trouble, you can try push your pressure points which you can find around your eyes. One is at the center point of your eyebrow and the others are in a diagonal line down from the corners of your noise. See this article about headache pressure points: https://www.healthline.com/health/pressure-points-for-headaches

I alsp find that regular deep breathing for about 10-15 minutes can really help. Breathe in for a count of 4, pause, then break out for a count of 4 (through your nose).

If all else fails I will take an aspirin or ibuprofen tablet because paracetamol doesn't work for me. Always ensure you have something to eat with a headache tablet to avoid giving yourself stomach ulcers.

Foods that soothe (or at least not aggravate) a headache are:

- bananas is known to fight headaches (due to the high quantities of vitamin B6)
- plain yoghurt
- plain potato
- whole grain bread

It is important to eat when you have a headache because low blood sugar (i.e. not eating) can cause a headache too!

Answer (score -1):

Half a glass of water with one lemon's juice reduces pain quickly.

Comment: It may happen from high blood pressure. If you drink such a water then it may effect your blood pressure.

Comment: citrus fruit causes migraines, so plain water is probably better